# iPhone rotation on demand

Tags: iphone, ipad, rotation, orientation

Is there a way to manually check current position of device AND ask device to automatically rotate it without waiting for user to actually rotate the device?

Currently I control the rotation with several IFs in -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation but in few situations I have to stop the view from rotating and enable it again and I don't want user to rotate the device twice to have the desired orientation.

Answer (score 0):

for checking Orientation

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

then based on your condition you can change device orientation as you wish..

you can use :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
```

or what ever you want.

or you can go for following but this is not do

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

Comment: The last line is exactly what I need ;) Is there such method?. I have had my rotation locked and I would like to change it once in a while manually to current orientation.

Comment: As I said this method is not documneted in apple but even you can use it. It works for me but I would Like to tell you that you have to use this method in viewWillAppear

Comment: Well it doesn't really work even in viewWillAppear for my iPad app. Is there really no way to state "rotate to landscape and from now on stay in landscape till I turn it off" ?

Comment: In viewWillAppear you can change device orientation and in viewWillDisappear het back in your desired orientation